# How to interpret type-II error probability while doing A/B testing?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, ab-test, type-i-and-ii-errors

I've been trying to familiarize myself with some of the statistics behind conducting A/B testing on a website and trying to pick a relevant sample size. I've come across several articles that talk about power analysis ([this is the best one that I have come across](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3004-ab-testing-tech-note-determining-sample-size)), and I'm trying to dive a little more into the theory.

1. The 37 signals post talks about doing a power analysis by using R's power.prop.test with a type-I error probability of 5% and a type-II error probability of 20%. This means that if after I run an A/B test with the given number of samples and the metric I am looking for is higher than the value I plugged into to the power analysis, it is very probable that the second variation had a positive effect. If it is not, it is very probable that the variation had no effect or a negative effect. Is this correct?
2. Assume that I want to iterate very quickly and therefore run a power analysis with a type-II error probability of 50% or even higher. My type-I error probability is still 5%. If I run the same A/B test with the lower sample number and the metric is again higher, can I still say that it is very probable that the B variation had a positive effect? However, if it is not higher, because my type-II error possibility is so high, I can make no conclusions about whether the second variation was ineffective or not?